# MySQL 1-many relationship issue

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables, one for Employees and one for Departments. One employee may only work in ONLY one department, but a department can have multiple employees. I have added a foreign key constraint between them, but If I attempt to add the same exact employee, with the same data to the same department, the query executes instead of failing.

```
create table Department(id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(100));

create table Employee(id int primary key auto_increment, 
                 department_id int not null,
                 name varchar(100),
                 foreign key (department_id) references department(id));

INSERT INTO Department(name) VALUES('China');
INSERT INTO Department(name) VALUES('England');

INSERT INTO Employee(department_id,name) VALUES (1,'Mark');
INSERT INTO Employee(department_id,name) VALUES (1,'Mark');
```

After inserting, for the 2nd time, Employee 'Mark', I was expecting an error but instead the query always executes. How can I restrict one specific employee to only work to one department?

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: MySQL, sorry for the wrong tag

Comment: Why were you expecting an error?

Comment: Be careful !! What happens if you have 2 employees with the same name ?!?! _It happens_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unique index on (`department_id`, `name`).

This will still allow the name mark within a other department.

```
ALTER TABLE `employee` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unique_department_id__name` (`department_id`, `name`);
```

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO Employee(department_id,NAME) VALUES (1,'Mark');
INSERT INTO Employee(department_id,NAME) VALUES (1,'Mark');
```

**Result**

```
Query: INSERT INTO Employee(department_id,name) VALUES (1,'Mark')

1 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.013 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.014 sec
-----------------------------------------------------------

Query: INSERT INTO Employee(department_id,name) VALUES (1,'Mark')

Error Code: 1062
Duplicate entry '1-Mark' for key 'unique_department_id__name'

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.003 sec
```

**EDITED**

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO Employee(department_id,NAME) VALUES (2,'Mark');
```

**Result**

```
Query: INSERT INTO Employee(department_id,NAME) VALUES (2,'Mark')

1 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.021 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.022 sec
```

Comment: What happens if you have 2 employees with the same name.

Comment: @RiggsFolly well i think the topic starter should add a last name column in table... makes more sense because two employee's with the same name can work add the same department

Comment: All I can say to that is `John Smith` or `Zhang Wei`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because  there is no constrains on Name column.

Add unique constrain Employee.name  .

eg

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_Person UNIQUE (name)
```

; 
,

Comment: Then what happens if you have 2 employees with the same name ??? Think before you jump

Comment: in that case this question is not valid and you have to create repeater employee  table there should trans table  for relation ship

Comment: @RiggsFoll this question will not be valid in that case . we need to create bridge table and have  pk s in that  tabes..